# Where does DNA fit on the Chomsky hierarchy?

Tags: dna, bioinformatics

Since adenine pairs with thymine and guanine pairs with cytosine, this seems to imply that there's a trivial Regular Expression for DNA (i.e. it's trivially a Regular Language, which is Type 3 on the [Chomsky hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy)). With that said, is there a "less trivial" Regular Expression for DNA? Or, even better, is there a "deeper" grammatical structure for DNA, such as a Context-Free Grammar?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about language hierarchies, and not biology per se.

Comment: @fileunderwater How is this not about biology? I'm asking a specific question about the overall structure of DNA - in particular, if we can find a structure of DNA on the Chomsky hierarchy.

Comment: Well, as a start, the theoretical background to your own question, and the only reference/link in it, goes to a wiki page on "*formal languages of computer science and linguistics*". Sure, you need knowlegde on DNA to answer it, but the question is dealing with language classes. That is my opinion though; others may disagree.

Comment: @fileunderwater The question's fundamentally about DNA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In truth DNA doesn't fit in the Chomsky hierarchy at all. DNA isn't a language, it is a complex molecule in a complex chemical environment. The fact that in many situations we can usefully abstract the structure of DNA as a string of four symbols should not obscure the underlying complexity. There is a [simple code that describes the aminos acids encoded by triples of nucleotides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_code), and [some elements of a "grammar" in the structure of genes if you squint (start codons, stop codons, introns, and exons)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_structure). But [much of the function of DNA is stochastic and driven by the biophysics of the binding of RNA and protein molecules to DNA.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_weight_matrix)